# mpstat from sysstat package is returning incorrect values

Tags: debian

I am trying to read CPU usage to make a live chart on a site, but...

When I for example run:

`mpsat -P ALL 1 10`

In one of the results for one core I got:

`11:31:06 PM    4    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00`

And what the hell does it supposed to mean?

Full stats:

```
11:31:05 PM  CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest   %idle
11:31:06 PM  all    5.07    0.00    9.85    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   85.07
11:31:06 PM    0    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
11:31:06 PM    1   34.00    0.00   66.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
11:31:06 PM    2    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
11:31:06 PM    3    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
11:31:06 PM    4    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
11:31:06 PM    5    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
11:31:06 PM    6    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
11:31:06 PM    7    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
```

Look at CPU no. 4... `?????`

Comment: What happens if you try `mpsat -P ON 1 10`?

Comment: You can also fill a bug there : https://github.com/sysstat/sysstat/issues